# How to run/execute Salesforce project/code from Eclipse IDE

Tags: apex, eclipse

We have a salesforce sandbox and it is running. We have apex codes and visualforce page on this project.

I have downloaded Eclipse Neon 4.6.3 and I have installed Force.com IDE version  38.0.

I have connected Eclipse to our Sandbox and I now have access to all the codes on Eclipse.

What do I have to do to execute/run this code/project in Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'run' ? Retrive coe from sandbox and make changes on it ?

Comment: Sorry, by run I mean like execute the code for testing purposes. Just like you develop a java console app and execute it by hitting the "Play" button. The play  button doesn't seem to do/run anything for the Salesforce project.

Comment: You've probably seen this but take a look at the guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm specifically the develop/test parts...

Comment: @CB4 - You don't run code per say. You deploy it. Not you can set breakpoints and do offline debugging using the logs but not with eclipse (AFAIK) in order to do that you would need IntelliJ Idea with Illuminated Cloud.- http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/offlinedebugger - Other option would be to pay for the Apex debugger which you can do from Eclipse but with IC and the offline debugger I have not found a reason to pay for it.